# Is WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(id).observe guaranteed to observe WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My current Android application employs

```
archWorkerRuntimeVersion = '2.3.0-beta02'

api "androidx.work:work-runtime:$archWorkerRuntimeVersion"
api "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$archWorkerRuntimeVersion"
```

I am observing the workers state via LiveData as follows:-

```
   WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(myWorkRequest.id).observe(lifeCycleOwner, Observer {
        if (it != null && it.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
            // DO SOMETHING IMPORTANT
        }
    })
```

Can I rely on always observing a state of `WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED`?

or could my observer not be presented with this state in some circumstances?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As mentioned in the docs, Enqueue state is used to indicate that the WorkRequest is enqueued and eligible to run when its
Constraints are met and resources are available. If your constraints are not met or resources are not available it might not enqueue.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo.State.html

Comment: Also, what kind of a workRequest is it? Is it a `PeriodicWorkRequest` or `OneTimeWorkRequest`. I know there can be issues with it if you are using `PeriodicWorkRequest`.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, I am using a OneTimeWorkRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed to observe though there few things that you have to keep on mind related to this API. Below is description is from google:

```
* Adds the given observer to the observers list. This call is similar to
 * {@link LiveData#observe(LifecycleOwner, Observer)} with a LifecycleOwner, which
 * is always active. This means that the given observer will receive all events and will never
 * be automatically removed. You should manually call {@link #removeObserver(Observer)} to stop
 * observing this LiveData.
 * While LiveData has one of such observers, it will be considered
 * as active.
 * <p>
 * If the observer was already added with an owner to this LiveData, LiveData throws an
 * {@link IllegalArgumentException}.
```

And below observe code should be called from Main thread otherwise the status will not be  latest

```
WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(myWorkRequest.id).observe(lifeCycleOwner, Observer {
    if (it != null && it.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
        // DO SOMETHING IMPORTANT
    }
})
```

Comment: The code above is associated with public void observeForever(@NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) {} NOT observe. I do not want to use observerForever(), I am employing observe with a lifecycle owner